# SCOM Monitoring for authentication failure reporting

Tags: email, authentication, alert, monitoring, scom

I'm totally new to SCOM. I need detailed steps in creating a monitoring in scom 2012, when ever someone who is not authorized to login, attempted to login set of machines I need to get an email alert. How can I do it? please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an event based monitor and look in the security log for the ID's associated with the events you want to trap.

This post describes it best:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/smsandmom/2008/11/12/opsmgr-2007-how-to-create-an-alert-rule-based-on-an-event-description/

Here's a video on how you do it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbYtnd2pemc

After the above is set up, you'll need to create the alert notification. You'll add yourself as a Subscriber in the admin panel of SCOM and create a subscription to email you the (Subscriber). Then you'll attach that subscription to the rule you created in the document above.

You'll see the detail steps here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212725(v=sc.12).aspx

You're asking a really broad question with lots of different steps, but this will get you started.